# The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})

Tags: java

I am getting the error, "The method addActionListener(ActionListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionListener(){})" for this code:

```
package JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class ActionListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("Title");
    frame.setLayout(null);

    frame.setResizable(false);

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int w = frame.getSize().width;
    int h = frame.getSize().height;
    int x = (dim.width-w)/2;
    int y = (dim.height-h)/2;

    frame.setLocation(x, y);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Press");
    b1.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
     b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  

            }    
     });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class' name is also named ActionListener and so the type JFrame.ActionListener is not applicable to java.awt.event.ActionListener. You have to qualify the class' name like here:

```
b1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  

        }    
 });
```

It would also be a good idea to rename your class to prevent this ambiguity in the first place.

Comment: Good catch.  _"It would also be a good idea to rename ..."_ - I would word that much more strongly, as in "Don't use names that are already in use in the library, it's a really bad idea". :-)